# POMP score in a bidirectional scale

Tags: effect-size, pre-post-comparison

I am working with some data that vary along an arbitrary scale of -1 to 1. More specifically, this scale refers to a difference between two scores (with 0 meaning no difference, 1 being the maximum possible difference when A>B, and -1 being the maximum possible difference when B>A)

I think it could be useful to express the observed scores as POMPs (Percent Of Maximum Possible score; Cohen, P., Cohen, J., Aiken, L. S., & West, S. G. (1999). The problem of units and the circumstance for POMP. Multivariate behavioral research, 34(3), 315-346). These scores are easy to calculate through the provided formula

100*[(observed-minimum)/(maximum-minimum)], where maximum/ minimum refers to the boundaries of the scale.

However, I am uncertain whether I should set minimum score = 0 (so score=0 retains the original meaning of no difference and the sign indicates the sign of the difference) or, to the contrary, I should calculate the POMP score considering minimum= -1 (in which case, 0 scores would become 50% of the maximum possible difference).

I thank you in advance for any possible answer

Comment: Could you elaborate on why it might be useful to re-express your data and why you chose this particular method?

Comment: As the article of Cohen et al. (1999) highlights, POMP scores might be especially useful when the original scale is arbitrary and they ease comparisons with alternative measures of the same construct (which can use a different scales). In this regard, and as the same article illustrates, POMP scores are sample independent, hence displaying several advantages over other possible transformations (e.g. Z and T scores),. Moreover, POMP scores preserve test statistics and statistical power, and convey immediate meaning.

Comment: This sounds like a mere linear transformation of the data.  Is there anything more to it than that?

Comment: You are right. This is "just" a linear transformation of the data. However,  it provides some gains at the interpretability and comparability levels without affecting the results of statistical comparisons or statistical power. Thus, for example, another researcher may construct a different instrument to measure the same construct but using a, let's say, -3 to 3 scale. POMP scores  would be comparable, while the original scores would be not. Moreover, by describing the effect as % of maximum possible helps to figure out the size of the effect in a scale without meaningful units

Comment: Since both the alternatives mentioned in your post are such linear transformations, the only basis for choosing among them would be "interpretability"--there appears to be no possibility of a statistical answer. However, because you present your situation abstractly, you haven't supplied any information about what interpretability might mean in this instance.  That makes it hard to answer your question.

Comment: Well, that's probably already an answer :-) If there are not statistical reasons to prefer any of both alternative I feel it might be better to use 0 as the minimum value for interpretability reasons (e.g. a POMP score of 0 equals to no difference and any other value expresses the size of the difference and its sign the direction of the difference).

Answer (score 0):

The logic of POMP scores suggests that assigning a score of 0 for no difference and allowing negative or positive scores would be just fine. I think I would label this as percentage change maybe (for clarity).

I don't think this is just an interpretation issue however. A z score scales using the standard deviation - this means that you have to choose a standardiser. This is fine if the population SD is known (and constant) but in practice one uses an SD from a sample (or if the SD is not constant in the population). This opens up to all sorts of measurement and estimation issues.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Thom Baguley. However, I am not sure why you mention SD in this context. The question does not refer to z-scores and the standardizer used in POMP is the maximum value, not SD. In fact, Cohen et al., introduced this procedure to overcome the problems associated with SD-based standardization. On the other hand, POMP is the term by which this form of standardization has been used for decades(see references in the original question) and I do not see how changing its name would provide clarity

Comment: Sorry for any confusion - it isn't indeed I who should have clearer. z scores were mentioned in the comments and the POMP scoring and as you noted POMP is  proposed as an alternative to the default of z scores in Psychology and related fields. If you use a linear scale that runs from -100 to +100 I'd maybe call that percentage increase/decrease. My reading of the Q was that the OP was unsure whether to scale -100 to 100 or 0 to 100. I'd argue that the 100 to +100 scaling is more readily interpretable in some contexts.

Comment: I have no intention of arguing about this issue. However, please note that z scores were only mentioned in comment #2 and in my initial comment to your answer, and in both cases, they were only mentioned to make a clear distinction between POMP and sd-based standardization. On the other hand, POMP should not be labelled as % of change/ decrease/increase, because it does not express "change" but relative size as compared to the possible maximum value in the considered variable. Finally, I agree that -100 to +100 might be easier to interpret in some contexts.

Comment: No argument needed. POMP shouldn't be labeled as % increase/decrease. A -100 to +100 scaling _might_ be in some contexts.